# How to count No. of occurrence of unique values in pandas DataFrame and save it as a new DataFrame

Tags: python, dataframe, count

Assume that I have a DataFrame. Every column has values which are repeated several times. I want to count the No. of occurrence of unique values (including Nan) in all columns, and save the results in a new DataFrame.

Example of DataFrame:

```
data = {
    'col_A': ['X', 'X', 'Y', 'Z', 'Z'],
    'col_B': ['Y', 'Y', np.nan, 'Z', 'Z'],
}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

And the results I would like to get:

```
index     col_A    col_B
X          2        0
Y          1        2
Z          2        2
nan        0        1
```

I appreciate it if you could guide on this problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```
df.apply(lambda x: pd.value_counts(x, dropna=False)).fillna(0).astype(int)
```

This code perform an `value_counts()` on each column and fill nans with 0.

Output:

```
     col_A  col_B
X        2      0
Y        1      2
Z        2      2
NaN      0      1
```